In-Memory Table Type with Primary Key causing Eager Index Spool
I have defined an In-Memory Table Type to hold a sequence of unique integers for the purpose of passing them between stored procedures.
The type has the following definition:
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[IntegerUniqueList] AS TABLE(
    [IntegerValue] [int] NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
(
    [IntegerValue] ASC
)
)
WITH ( MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON )

In complex queries that use it, even though an index seek seems the obvious choice, the optimizer is choosing to include an Index Spool. This is defeating the point of having the data in memory.
This can be replicated in AdventureWorks2019 with the following:
DECLARE @IDs dbo.IntegerUniqueList
INSERT  @IDs (IntegerValue)
SELECT  p.BusinessEntityID
FROM    Person.BusinessEntity p

SELECT  p.BusinessEntityID
FROM    Person.Person p
WHERE   (p.BusinessEntityID = 1)
        OR  (
                (
                    (0 = 1)
                    OR  EXISTS (
                                SELECT  1
                                FROM    Person.BusinessEntity be
                                JOIN    Person.BusinessEntityAddress bea ON (bea.BusinessEntityID = be.BusinessEntityID)
                                JOIN    Person.Address a ON (a.AddressID = bea.AddressID)
                                WHERE   (bea.AddressTypeID = 2)
                                        AND (be.BusinessEntityID = p.BusinessEntityID)
                                        AND (a.AddressLine1 LIKE N'%1%')
                            )
                )
                AND EXISTS (
                            SELECT  1
                            FROM    @IDs id
                            WHERE   (id.IntegerValue = p.BusinessEntityID)
                        )
            )

Here is the plan produced: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SkFipTYTR
If I remove the in-memory aspect, or change the NONCLUSTERED Primary Key to use a HASH index, the spool goes away. Given that in-memory should give better performance and I can't predict how many rows will be put in the variables to predict a reasonable BUCKET_COUNT, neither of those solutions is ideal.
What's going on here and are there any other options to prevent the spool?

nope
The premise that in-memory should have better performance for select queries is absolutely false. The ideal use-case for it is "hot" data that is under frequent, highly-concurrent modifications.
Think shock absorber tables for things like online gambling or trying to order tickets for an Oasis reunion. What you're using it for has none of that action. The in-memory feature has its uses, but it has been oversold as a general performance feature.
You may want to rethink this approach and just use a regular #temp table with a clustered index on IntegerValue. That would have additional benefits:

Allow for a parallel insert plan, which may be a general performance consideration
Allow for statistics to be built on the IntegerValue column, which may dictate better plan choice


I also use them for transferring data from my application into stored procedures, otherwise I would use temp tables almost exclusively for those reasons. I get your point though. It sure seemed like a good idea at the time...

@DanDef you can still put the TVP contents into a temp table once the stored procedure executes. It's not an uncommon tactic.
